# Allow web server to edit files inside a docker container

Tags: php, web, permissions, docker, apache2

I'm trying to setup docker as web developer environment on my mac. I share local volume from my machine to web root folder inside a container. But I got stuck with permissions, web-server inside docker can't create a new folder or write new files to shared volume because almost all files have permissions 744 and different a user and a group.

- I thought make all permissions 777 but it doesn't sounds good because in the git and in future on a server it will be also with bad permissions. In any way, a new files and folder that is creating web-server have wrong permissions.
- I thought make a same group name on my mac that running web server inside docker (www-data) and change permissions to 774. But it sounds stupid.

What is a best way to fast manage files inside a docker? In my way I need to edit PHP files and immediately see result in browser.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `docker exec -it container_id script` script being either a sed or a replacement of your file with a new version.

Starting with docker 1.8, you can add a specific user, `docker exec -u muyser`